# Radius of convergence of $\tanh(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Why Taylor series expansion of $\tanh(x)$ only valid for $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ whereas there are no singularities of $\tanh(x)$ in the reals.

Comment: Given that you wrote it in your question, have you actually *tried* finding the radius of convergence?

Comment: Because there is a singularity in the complex plane, at $\pm i\pi/2$. Note that $\tanh (ix)=i\tan (x)$.

Comment: I tried a lot,  but i failed

Comment: But i am taking about real, u mean that singularity in complex implies singularity in real?

Comment: It does not imply a singularity in the reals but it does limit the radius of convergence which applies to the reals as well.  This is surprising when you first see it.